# In C, is there a way to declare an instance of a structure that is always addressed by a particular pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I'll start by cataloging what I know to distinguish that from what I want:

1. I can declare a "template" for a structure through `typedef struct astruct...'
2. I can declare an instance of a structure, in global or local storage, through `astruct mystruct;`
3. I can declare a pointer to a structure through `astruct *pmystruct;` and then set the value of that pointer to an instance through `pmystruct = &mystruct;`

What I'd like is to do sort of the opposite of #3:  I'd like to declare an instance of a structure that is defined to be addressed by a particular pointer...something akin to:

```
astruct *pthestruct;
astruct thestruct referencedby(pthestruct);
```

Then, I would not need to prefix any reference to a field within the struct with `pthestruct -> thestruct.structdataitem`

This is accomplished in PL/I by using the `BASED` attibute on the declaration:

```
DCL PTHESTRUCT POINTER;
DCL 1 THESTRUCT BASED(PTHESTRUCT),
      3 ... (rest of the structure) ;
```

In the code all references to THESTRUCT will be implicitly "based" off the address in `PTHESTRUCT`, just as if I had coded `PTHESTRUCT -> THESTRUCT`.

Ideas?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: use `&pthestruct`

Comment: I'm confused by your `pthestruct -> thestruct.structdataitem`. Surely it would just be `pthestruct->structdataitem`?

Comment: I can't think of a way to magically initialize a pointer in the way you want. Just do things the C way, since you are writing C code.

Comment: Scott Fagen, Why not use `pthestruct->`?

Comment: I understand the distinction between a `typedef struct` and a `struct`.  I'm looking to see if the functionality, `BASED(ptr-expression)`, available in PL/I (and variants), is in C.  

From the answers and comments, it would appear not to be a feature of the language.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `thestruct` to refer to the `*pstruct` for the value of `pstruct` at the time of assignment/definition of `thestruct`, then C++ has this in its references feature, but C does not.

If you want `thestruct` to refer to `*pstruct` for the value of `pstruct` at the time `thestruct` is used, then this can be accomplished with a macro:

```
#define thestruct (*pstruct)
```

In many circumstances, this would be considered bad practice.

Comment: Fundamentally, I'd like to set up a particular instance of a structure to be 'attached'  to a particular pointer, so that I don't have to type `pointer->` in front of every reference.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
struct whatever object[1];
```

You can now use the object itself

```
object[0].field = 42;
foo(object[0]); // pass a copy
```

or the (array converted to) pointer

```
object->field = 42;
bar(object); // pass a pointer
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean ?

```
  typedef struct
    {
     int a;
     int b;
    } struct_t;

    struct_t myStruct;
    struct_t* pStruct;

   pStruct = &myStruct;
   pStruct->a =5;
```

Comment: No, I'd like the pointer that is somehow connected to the declared structure. so that if I change the pointer, the memory referenced by references to the structure is changed.

If I borrow the syntax from PL/I:

`typedef astruct {....} astruct *pastruct;  // Create the typedef "template"
pastruct pmystruct;  // Declare a pointer for mystruct
astruct mystruct based(pystruct); // Declare an instance of astruct that "floats" with pmystruct`

Anytime I change the value of pmystruct, the memory that mystruct references changes with it.